# magento in not sending emails after host move

Tags: php, email, magento, move, host

I recently bought a vps hosting account for my magento store beacause it was getting to big for the old host (20000+ products).
I did not change the ns for the domain yet because i want to be sure that everything works properly before the 48 h propagation downtime.

Among the things i observed is that magento is not sending any email to my customers, i mean any, not even the reset password email.

I'm baffled about this problem because the setting are all in order ( like my old old host ).

Does the fact that i dident change the ns has something to do it ?

================== EDIT =====================

managed to get it to send an confirmation email to the customer but cant get it to send copy of the mail to the admin.

Comment: It could be anything. You should look at the error logs and check the mail server configuration. I can't believe that the system is an *exact mirror* of your old one.

Comment: judt did a quick check and evert thing seams to be in order, does the fact that i dident change the ns has something to do it ?

Comment: Please post: Operating system, MTA, target service (if any standard like gmail, AOL, etc.), did you try different services, does sending from other applications/scripts work, do you have console access

Comment: Does your new host have sendmail enabled?  Turn on logging and see if there are any exceptions being thrown in /var/log/system.log.  Also, you can decrease the TTL on your DNS setting now which will eliminate the propagation downtime when you do migrate the DNS settings.

Comment: dualed CENTOS 5.9 x86_64 kvm ; sendmail , yap a have console acces

Comment: just tried sending an e mail from an account with no problems

Comment: yap sendmail seems to be enabled on the host

Comment: T00:34:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos() [<a href='function.strpos'>function.strpos</a>]: Empty delimiter  in /home/rraz4580/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 510
 in syslog but nothing regarding mail :)

Comment: Please post output of `mailq`. And what do you mean by "just tried sending an e mail from an account with no problems"? Also, what about my other questions especially "does sending from other applications/scripts work?" (on the same server of course!)

Answer (score 0):

yes, if your name server wasn't changed your MX records won't match. your emails are being discarded by your web host or something else in between because they are spam worthy until your MX records match.

Comment: so when i will change the ns to the new domain, theoreticaly will work ?

Comment: well when you change your name servers to your new web host yes.

Comment: managed to get it to send an confirmation email to the customer but cant get it to send copy of the mail to the admin. As i understand tons of people have the same problem.

Comment: hello again, the ns have propagated ok, and still no joy. I can only get the customer confirmation mail, but not the admin copy. All of the  backend emails are google aps group emails... can this be the issue. after reasearch i found out that google has an issue with sending mail from group email to email inside that group. Weird one, this issue be :)) (as master Yoda would say)

Comment: If the MX records haven't been changed, your new server is trying to relay email and if this is through another hosting service's mail server, it's considered spam and dropped. The MX records will have to change so that your local sendmail/exim installation is sending through your local MX that's trusted to send for your web server.

Comment: just get in contact with your new web host and they can help you.